# Download Image from api using angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs

Hi need some help please 
i want to download image file from api and save it into my local storage
i have this code but i only get is the base64 of image? thank you

```
  function toDataURL(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                callback(reader.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send();
    }

    toDataURL('http://iams.intellismartinc.com:8081/App_Content/Files/EPP_Item/5c36cae0-780e-4810-b5f5-a513468a581f.jpg', function(dataUrl) {
        console.log('RESULT:', dataUrl)
    })
```

Comment: Do you have an Angular app set up? Why are you using `XMLHttpRequest()` and not Angular's `$http` service?

Comment: hi sir im not really sure i got that code from other source but i want to know how can i download the image using given API